# Como edito o width de uma classe usando angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um elemento com duas classes:

```
 <div class="classe1 classe2">

 </div>
```

Quero aumentar o width do meu estilo da classe 2,
qual seria a forma correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Quer editar o `width` da classe ou da `div`? Caso seja da `div` seria mais simples editar o estilo. Se quiser alterar o `width` da classe mesmo para que afecte todos os elementos, talvez a melhor seja fazer *override* da classe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uma das formas correctas de o fazer será dar o width correcto a uma nova class, `widthClass` (por exemplo) e depois fazer um `ng-class`.

`widthClass { width: 9000px }`

`<div ng-class="'widthClass': scope.needsMoreWidth" class="class1 class2"></div>`

No teu controlador vais ter algo como:

`$scope.needsMoreWidth = true;`

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser aplicar o width a todos os elementos que aplicam a classe, no caso "classe2", em tempo de execução, você pode aplicar.

`angular.element(".class2").width(500)`